# No any metric definitions for Azure Load Balancer resource

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-monitoring, azure-load-balancer

I try to retrieve Azure Metrics using [Azure Monitor API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/).

I use `MonitorManagementClient` class from [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor/) nuget package.

I need to get metric definitions from the [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metricdefinitions/list) using next code snippet:

```
client.MetricDefinitions.List(resourceId)
```

My code snippet works perfectly on other Azure resource types like Azure Traffic Manager, Azure Application Gateway, Azure Express Route, etc.

But I don't see any metric definitions for **Azure Load Balancer**.

Why metric definitions are missed for **Azure Load Balancer** resource type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just for the `Standard` SKUs, I test with that, it works. Also I can reproduce your issue with a `Basic` one.

See the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-metric-near-real-time#metrics-and-dimensions-supported):

[image]